# Animate objects along normals using Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, normals, simulation-nodes

I am attempting to create a Geometry nodes workflow that will animate arrows along normals. The initial arrow setup is easy enough, but how to get them to animate/follow the normals is another challenge.  My attempted solution uses simulation nodes - but that only moves them in globe/local space as a whole. I don't see a way to move them along normals. What am I missing? Thank you. [image] [image]

Comment: if you don't want to move in local space, you could probably uncheck the 'local' checkbox on the translate instances node (or use a 'set position').